# What's the purpose to bit-shift int value by zero?

Tags: java, bit-shift

Looking to the source code of java.nio.DirectByteBuffer class, I have found this:

```
if ((length << 0) > Bits.JNI_COPY_TO_ARRAY_THRESHOLD) ....
```

What is the purpose to shift length by zero bits? May this be some perfomance optimization or something else?

Comment: I've never seen that word in your posting title used as in this context.

Comment: Good question. I took a look at the source code and noticed that this idiom is used several times. Mysterious.

Comment: Some guys wanted to check if javac is correctly removing them.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut are you guessing, or do you have firm info that this is how that code made it into the Java src?

Comment: Just a joke. Tried to be funny though.

Comment: The more complicated the code looks to your boss, the smarter you will be perceived by him. If the code is simple, why should he raise your salary?

Answer (score 17):

I think I've solved it.

In the class JavaDocs:

```
// -- This file was mechanically generated: Do not edit! -- //
```

So it is not hand coded. It was script-generated and the script writer did not add an optimisation for the case when the amount to bit shift by is zero.

Comment: For ShortBuffer, IntBuffer, LongBuffer the offsets are multiplied by 2, 4, 8 etc by left shifting. Optimising away the << 0 case would complicate the generation code for no practical gain.

Answer (score 3):

Doing `i << 0` is a no-op. It evaluates to the same as `i`.

Comment: This explains the output of the operation, but it doesn't really explain the real question - why write code to do this?

Comment: The question was, *what's the purpose* and my answer indicates that it can't possibly have a sensible purpose.

Comment: @mattb - If you are going to nitpick an answer, it pays to understand what the words of the question actually, literally say.

Comment: @mattb I'm a year late, but I'm doing it now and it's in a loop that reaches 0. It's redundant, but it is good to know that it's a null-op so it doesn't break anything.

Answer (score 2):

The `i << 0` is plainly redundant. There is no good reason for a Java programmer to write this code deliberately.

I'd say that this code is:

- written by someone who wasn't thinking,
- written by someone who doesn't understand what the `<<` operator does,
- the result of some semi-mechanical refactoring, or
- originally produced by some sort of code generator or translator.

However, there's a good chance that the bytecode or JIT compiler will optimize this away, or that it won't impact significantly on performance anyway.